# Get sums from pandas series with categorical values

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently working with a dataframe containing order information about t-shirts in which I have a series that looks like this:

```
 '2 s',
 '1 s 2 l',
 '1 s 1 m',
 '1 m 1 l',
 '2 xl',
 '1 s',
 '1 m',
 '1 s',
 '1 m',
 '1 m',
 '1 m',
 '1 s 1 xl',
 '1xxl 1x 2xl',
```

These data points are manually inputed and I am looking for a way to find the sum of items for a particular size ie. I'd like to find the sum of all s, all m, etc. Atm I am a bit unsure of how to proceed; I am thinking of splitting each entry and doing some encoding and then using groupbys.

Comment: Seems like the inputs are too free-form. Like how is the last line supposed to be interpreted? `1xxl 1x 2xl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have dataframe:

```
          sizes
0           2 s
1       1 s 2 l
2       1 s 1 m
3       1 m 1 l
4          2 xl
5           1 s
6           1 m
7           1 s
8           1 m
9           1 m
10          1 m
11     1 s 1 xl
12  1xxl 1x 2xl
```

Then:

```
df = (
    df["sizes"]
    .str.extractall(r"(\d+)([\sa-z]+)")
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .rename(columns={0: "count", 1: "size"})
)
df["size"] = df["size"].str.strip()
df["count"] = df["count"].astype(int)

print(df.pivot_table(columns="size", aggfunc="sum"))
```

Prints:

```
size   l  m  s  x  xl  xxl
count  3  6  7  1   5    1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think andrej left a good answer to the question, but maybe for new users it would also be useful to spell out what's going on

1. We want to use some regex extraction from Series.str.extractall() to capture matching groups, here the groups are (1 or more digits) followed by (1 or more letters).  If extractall finds more than one set of matches, those are written on new rows with an index saying which match number it is
2. Resetting the index gets rid of the "match index", and of course you can rename columns and format the values appropriately

```
>>> df
         sizes
0          2 s
1          1 l
2      1 m 1 l
3  1xxl 1x 2xl
>>> df['sizes'].str.extractall(r"(\d+)([\sa-z]+)")
         0     1
  match
0 0      2     s
1 0      1     l
2 0      1    m
  1      1     l
3 0      1  xxl
  1      1    x
  2      2    xl
>>> df['sizes'].str.extractall(r"(\d+)([\sa-z]+)").reset_index(drop=True)
   0     1
0  2     s
1  1     l
2  1    m
3  1     l
4  1  xxl
5  1    x
6  2    xl
```